# How to GroupBy based on GetDate() , CASE and fixed column aliases

Tags: sql, t-sql, alias

I am trying to create an openAR file and I am stuck trying to group this data by Customer and Invoice. The file will get created daily.

| [FILE DATE] | [CUSTOMER ID] | [INVOICE NUMBER] | [INVOICE TYPE] | [INVOICE DATE] | [OPEN INVOICE AMOUNT] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | INV1000 | INV | 06/08/2020 | 1000 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | INV1001 | INV | 06/15/2020 | 50 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | INV1002 | INV | 08/20/2020 | 50 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | INV1005 | CM | 10/18/2020 | -100 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | PAY1000 | PAY | 06/15/2020 | -750 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | PAY1000 | PAY | 06/15/2020 | 820 |

I am trying to group this data as I need to Sum lines of the open invoice amounts per each invoice. The file will get exported automatically to another company to process the AR info. The column headers need to be exact as they are below. I usually use Aliases to group but with 2 word fixed Column headers, I am a bit stuck to figure out how to group this code. Also, how would you group GETDATE() and that CASE statement?

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT (nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 101) as [FILE DATE],
   GACC.BPR_0 as [CUSTOMER ID],
   GACC.NUM_0 as [INVOICE NUMBER],
   GACC.TYP_0 as [INVOICE TYPE], 
   Case
        When GACC.TYP_0 in ('INV', 'CM') Then CONVERT (nvarchar(30), SI.BPRDAT_0 , 101)
        Else CONVERT (nvarchar(30), PAY.ACCDAT_0 , 101)
   End as [INVOICE DATE],
  (GACC.AMOUNT_0 * GACC.SNS_0) as [OPEN INVOICE AMOUNT]  --- want to SUM and group this column  for each INV#
  FROM dbo.GACCDUDATE as GACC
  left join dbo.SINVOICE as SI --- Invoice Table
  on GACC.NUM_0 = SIV.NUM_0
  left join dbo.PAYMENT as PAY -- Payment Table
  on PAY.NUM_0 = GACC.NUM_0
```

Thank you so much for helping me to group this for each customer, invoice, sum of open amount.

Edit - Desired output

| [FILE DATE] | [CUSTOMER ID] | [INVOICE NUMBER] | [INVOICE TYPE] | [INVOICE DATE] | [OPEN INVOICE AMOUNT] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | INV1000 | INV | 06/08/2020 | 1000 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | INV1001 | INV | 06/15/2020 | 50 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | INV1002 | INV | 08/20/2020 | 50 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | INV1005 | CM | 10/18/2020 | -100 |
| 01/22/2021 | 00100000 | PAY1000 | PAY | 06/15/2020 | 70 |

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: If you want to use group by then you have to include all columns that are not aggregated. If you need to include non-aggregated columns then look up window functions

Comment: Correct, but it is not allowing we to use groupby when my alias for my case statement is [INVOICE DATE] or [FILE DATE] in the first column. I can use fields in groupby for the other columns.

Comment: Just wrap your query in a Common Table Expression and then you can reference your alias in  the CTE in a further query avoiding any problem with aliases. Or just group by CONVERT (nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 101). CTE is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE to reference aliases. Alternatively, as in my comment just group on `"CONVERT (nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 101)"` or `"(GACC.AMOUNT_0 * GACC.SNS_0)"`

```
With MyInvoices as 
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT (nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 101) as [FILE DATE],
        GACC.BPR_0 as [CUSTOMER ID],
        GACC.NUM_0 as [INVOICE NUMBER],
        GACC.TYP_0 as [INVOICE TYPE], 
        Case
        When GACC.TYP_0 in ('INV', 'CM') Then CONVERT (nvarchar(30), SI.BPRDAT_0 , 101)
        Else CONVERT (nvarchar(30), PAY.ACCDAT_0 , 101)
        End as [INVOICE DATE],
        (GACC.AMOUNT_0 * GACC.SNS_0) as [OPEN INVOICE AMOUNT]   
    FROM dbo.GACCDUDATE as GACC
    left join dbo.SINVOICE as SI 
    on GACC.NUM_0 = SIV.NUM_0
    left join dbo.PAYMENT as PAY  
    on PAY.NUM_0 = GACC.NUM_0
)
select [FILE DATE], [CUSTOMER ID], [INVOICE NUMBER], [INVOICE TYPE],[INVOICE DATE],[OPEN INVOICE AMOUNT] from MyInvoices
group by  [FILE DATE], [CUSTOMER ID], [INVOICE NUMBER], [INVOICE TYPE],[INVOICE DATE]
```

Comment: Johnny, thank you so much! This definitely did the trick!